# What is the correct format for nested associations in an rspec controller test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, associations

In an rspec controller specification, what is the correct way to define the `valid_attributes` method when your model `has_one` association?

*Rails 3.2.12, rspec 2.12, factory_girl_rails 4.2.1*

if you create a new Rails project with two models, Person and Brain, like so:

```
rails new crowd
cd crowd
rails g scaffold person name:string
rails g scaffold brain weight_kg:float
```

(And do all the legwork to associate them), you can end up with these models:

```ruby
class Brain < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  attr_accessible :weight_kg
  attr_accessible :person
  attr_accessible :person_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :person
end
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :brain
  attr_accessible :name
  attr_accessible :brain
  attr_accessible :brain_attributes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :brain
  validates :brain, :presence => { :message => "Please give me a brain" }
end
```

**Relevant auto-generated content of spec/controllers/people_controller_spec.rb:**

```
describe PeopleController do
  def valid_attributes
    {
        "name" => "A Person",
    }
  end
```

At this point valid_attributes is invalid for a Person, because it's missing a Brain.  Okay, let's add one.  But how?

**Wrong:**

```
  def valid_attributes
    {
        "name" => "A Person",
        "brain" => { "weight_kg" => "25" }
    }
  end
```

^  Generates `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Brain(#86698290) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#84831840)`

**Wrong:**

```
  def valid_attributes
    {
        "name" => "A Person",
        "brain" => Brain.new(:weight_kg => 25)
    }
  end
```

^ Because it won't save. The errors will be `Expected response to be a <:redirect>, but was <200>` and `expected persisted? to return true, got false` and 2 others.

**Wrong:** (assuming a valid spec/factories/brain.rb)

```
  def valid_attributes
    {
        "name" => "A Person",
        "brain" => FactoryGirl.build(:brain),
    }
  end
```

^ This is wrong because this also will not save a `person` record on create/update. The errors will be `Expected response to be a <:redirect>, but was <200>` and `expected persisted? to return true, got false` and 2 others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```ruby
  def valid_attributes
    {
        "name" => "A Person",
        "brain_attributes" => { "weight_kg" => "25" }
    }
```

Or

```ruby
  def valid_attributes
    {
        "name" => "A Person",
        "brain_attributes" => FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:brain)
    }
```